# Why do some artist have "live" listed with their name in concert line-ups?

Tags: concert

I have noticed for some concerts/festivals that some bands (apparently, mostly EDM/DJs) will have "live" listed with their name on a line-up.  For example:

Check out **Matador** on this [line-up](http://suncitymusicfestival.com/blog/presenting-complete-lineup-2016) for the Sun City Music Festival (2nd line form the bottom, listed as **Matador live**)

There are a couple more examples on this [line-up](https://ultramusicfestival.com/lineup/) for Ultra Music festival (**Thomas Jack** and **Fakear** in the support section).

As far as I can tell "live" is clearly not a part of the actual band name.

I know DJs and EDM artists aren't exactly playing traditional instruments like other genres of music (cue the "they just push play on their laptop" comments), but if that were the reason for the "live" in the line-up (mixing live vs. playing a prerecorded set) I would imagine there would be at least a few more "live" bands listed.  I could be very wrong however.

So, how does a band listed as "live" on a line-up differ from the others?  Isn't everyone there "live" in person?

Answer (score 2):

It just means they're doing an actual show, not just performing a DJ set.

Answer (score 1):

They may be live in person, but that may not mean they are playing live, as in actually playing their instruments or singing live.

Comment: I figured that was a possibility, but between EDM artists/DJs from what I've seen live they don't sing live and they just have their equipment in front of them.  So, how would two artists doing that differ if one were listed as "live" and the other not?  That was more the question I was trying to ask.

Comment: I'm nt too into EDM, so I could only guess that the DJ is mixing live, picking the running order of what they play depending on the mood of the crowd etc. But I'm not sure -- has there ever been a case of a DJ just sticking a mix CD on they made and 'pretending' they are mixing live etc? Like I said, I am not an EDM/DJ guy, so I am only guessing.